# use of "enter" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "enter" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually?If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The chamber is open at the bottom in order to **enter** incident wave.

[image]

> "in order to **admit** the incident wave" is OK?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

Your wording is incorrect, because you are saying that the chamber is entering the wave, whereas I'm sure what you actually want to say is that the wave is entering the chamber.

If you want to use the word **enter** here, you would say:

> The chamber is open at the bottom in order **for the incident wave to enter.**

If you want to keep your sentence structure, you would need to change the verb. "Receive" might be the one:

> The chamber is open at the bottom in order to **receive** the incident wave.

Comment: "... to allow entry of the incident wave." is another inelegant but grammatical option.

Answer (score 1):

The chamber is open at the bottom in order to enter incident wave.

Rewrite: The bottom of the chamber is open so the incident wave may enter it.

An X enters a Y. The X enters Y [it].